# What does "graphic" mean in "a graphic video"? Is it an official term?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Googling "graphic video" revelas that it is something like "video with violence", yet I can't find "graphic video" in a dictionary.

[Description](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/graphic) of "graphic" sometimes give a hint:

> depicted in a realistic or vivid manner:
>     Example: graphic sex and violence.

, but the definition doesn't not imply any violence, only the example.

Is it appropriate to use the term "graphic video" just for a realistic or picturesque video? Isn't "graphic video" a tautology (video implies relating to graphics, like audio to sound)? Is it some euphemism?

Comment: Is just question better here or on english.SE?

Comment: The meaning of "graphic" really depends on context.  In general a "graphic video" doesn't mean "a video with pictures", because as you point out, all video includes pictures by definition.  "Graphic video"  does not mean "realistic video" and "picturesque" is very different from either "graphic" or "realistic".  It's not the kind of phrase you would find in a dictionary, since the precise meaning of "graphic" is mostly just understood from context.

Comment: @Vi: I believe you asked in the right place when you asked it here. BTW, this is a very good question; I hope the community leaves some very informative and helpful answers.

Comment: I concur with J.R., but I do not understand what _official_ connotes in this context.

Answer (score 4):

> graphic video

is a term used to describe a video which shows *everything* and has a negative meaning

> graphic violence

will show all the blood and gore that might be seen in real-life

> graphic pornography

will show sex acts up close.

A usual word which is collocated wth graphic is

> graphic detail

If one was showing detailed videos of landscapes one might use

> detailed
>   real-life

as adjectives instead of "graphic".

This is not to be confused with

> graphic**s**

which refers to technical display aspects.

> interactive graphics

refers to graphs that the user can control and change instantly

> graphics video card

is the printed circuit board which sends signals to drive a display device like a CRT or TV

Answer (score 0):

***Graphic*** here means *detailed* (including tiny details important or unimportant as in real life) since the video does not necessarily include all the details.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).